# Django Test | How to pass a a dictionary containing a dictionary value through clients.post

Tags: django, django-tests

I have a dictionary `A` that contains a single  value that is also a dictionary `B`

```
B = {"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2", "k3": "v3",}
A = {"User": B}
```

This type of dictionary is used in one of my `views` function

```
def views_function(request):
   # request.data is a dictionary containing a single value that is also a dictionary. Just like A
```

I'm trying to write a unit test for `views_function` from `django.test.TestCase`.

```
from django.test import TestCase

class test_cases(TestCase):
    
    def setUp(self):
        self.B = {"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2", "k3": "v3",}
        self.A = {"User": self.B}
        self.url = reverse("views_function_url")

    def test_views_function(self):
        response = self.client.post(url, self.A, format="json")
```

But `clients.post` seems unable to take `A` as an input. When I print `A` inside `test_views_function` it shows the proper dictionary.

```
def test_views_function(self):
    B = {"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2", "k3": "v3",}
    A = {"User": B}
    print(A)  # {"User": {"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2", "k3": "v3"}}
    response = self.client.post(url, A, format="json")
```

But when I add a print statement to `views_function` for some reason only the last key of `B` is there

```
def views_function(request):
   print(request.data.dict()) # {'User': 'k3'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was simple, I had the wrong argument by accident. It's `content_type="application/json"` not `format="json"` in `self.client.post()`